# I want to display categories and its products in list.phtml in Magento

Tags: magento

I'm new in Magento and I need to display categories as heading and the list all products under this category. Somehow I got some relevant code while searching the web, but it is not working. Could display categories as heading but cannot display its corresponding products.

I will provide the code which i used to display the categories and products.

```
<?php 

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$tree = $category->getTreeModel();

$tree->load();
$ids = $tree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$arr = array();

if ($ids){
    foreach ($ids as $id){
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $cat->load($id);
        if ($cat->getIsActive()) {
            $arr[$id] = $cat->getName();
            $arr[$catId] =  $cat->getId();


?>

<div class="right">
                    <div class="products">
                    <h2 class="head"><?php echo $arr[$id]; ?></h2>
<?php 
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id); //where $category_id is the id of the category

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product

$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image')); //add product attribute to be fetched

//$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'); //uncomment to get products in random order

$collection->addStoreFilter();

if(!empty($collection))

{

    foreach ($collection as $_product):


    ?>                      
                    <div class="pro-list">

  <h5><?php echo $_product->getname(); ?></h5>
 <!-- other product details -->
  </div>
 <?php 
 endforeach;

 }else

 {

    echo 'No products exists';

 }


 ?> 
</div>
</div>
<?php }
        }
        }
        ?>
```

What I am doing wrong? The code is written in `template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean when you say "display categories as heading and the list all products under this category"? Do you need to display ALL categories with their products on a single page?

Comment: Magento will display category as heading and all products listed in that category by default. You don't need to write any code for that. If you go Catalogue>Categories you can manage the settings of that category (see if the category is active, see what products are listed in the category and more).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding ,i concluded with this solution :

```
<?php $helper = $this->helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $categories = $this->getStoreCategories() ?>
    <div id="navigation_vert">
        <?php if (count($categories) > 0): ?>
            <ul>
                <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a class="link" href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>">
                        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($category->getName()) ?>
                        </a>
                        <?php $subcategories = $category->getChildren() ?>
                        <?php if (count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
                            <?php foreach($subcategories as $subcategory): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subcategory) ?>">
                                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?>
                                </a>
                                    <?php $subsubcategories = $subcategory->getChildren() ?>
                                    <?php if (count($subsubcategories) > 0): ?>
                                        <ul>
                                            <?php foreach($subsubcategories as $subsubcategory): ?>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($subsubcategory) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml(trim($subsubcategory->getName(), '- ')) ?></a>
                                                    </li>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    <?php endif; ?><!-- subsubcategories if e -->
                            <?php endforeach; ?><!-- subcategories for e -->
                        <?php endif; ?><!-- subcategories if e -->
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?><!-- categories e -->
            </ul>
        <?php endif; ?><!-- count main categories if e -->
    </div><!-- id navigation_vert e -->
```

Here in the above code we have extracted all categories (its sub categories--->and its sub sub categories(just for reference))
    Every category is associated with `<a>` tag.
    On clicking ,all the respective category's products would be displayed (in a list/grid pattern).
    Common mistakes [while managing categories.](http://www.aschroder.com/2009/03/top-3-solutions-when-your-magento-categories-are-not-displaying/)
    For managing products check this link [How to manage products](http://www.sboeconnect.com/blog/magentocommerce/adding-deleting-and-managing-products-in-magento-commerce-3.html)
    Reasons for not [displaying products.](http://www.aschroder.com/2010/07/why-are-my-magento-products-not-showing-up/)

Comment: please don't shout (aka: bold everything) at us

Comment: strange ! I was not knowing writing in bold is considered as shouting.BTW Fine with edit.